# addToSet and set in same update using PyMongo and MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

In MongoDb is it possible to perform an update on everything except a field that has already been updated for example with addToSet?

I'm storing information in a python dictionary which is updated by the user.  I then want to use this dictionary to update the entry in MongoDb.  One of the fields is an array and I want to insert the dictionary value if it's not there.  Everything else can be replaced.  The problem I have is that using set with the whole dictionary replaces the array with the single value.  To illustrate the problem:

I create a dictionary

```
thing = {}
thing['name'] = 'fruit'
thing['color'] = 'green'
thing['types'] = ['apple', 'pear', 'kiwi']
```

I insert it:

```
c_users.insert_one(thing)
```

A user marks some fields to update

```
thing2 = {}
thing2['name'] = 'fruit'
thing2['color'] = 'darkgreen'
thing2['types'] = 'mango'
```

Then I try to update the database

c_users.update({'name':thing2['name']}, {'$addToSet':{'types':thing2['types']},'$set':{'color':thing2}})

Is it possible to get this method working?  There are other ways to achieve the same end result if not, such as using a variable instead of thing2['types'] but it would be better to keep all the values in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pop the 'types' value out of the update document:

```
>>> c_users.find_one()
{u'color': u'green', u'_id': ObjectId('553fddc967d5bd0b07022477'), u'name': u'fruit', u'types': [u'apple', u'pear', u'kiwi']}
>>> thing2 = {'name': 'fruit', 'color': 'darkgreen', 'types': 'mango'}
>>> c_users.update({'name': thing2['name']}, {'$addToSet': {'types': thing2.pop('types')}, '$set': thing2}) 
{u'nModified': 1, u'ok': 1, u'n': 1, 'updatedExisting': True, u'electionId': ObjectId('553fc845f09926d0bb959eb7'), u'lastOp': Timestamp(1430249053, 1)}
>>> c_users.find_one()
{u'color': u'darkgreen', u'_id': ObjectId('553fddc967d5bd0b07022477'), u'name': u'fruit', u'types': [u'apple', u'pear', u'kiwi', u'mango']}
```